# Меридиональный и меридианный

Tags: орфография

Со словом "меридиональный" заморочка у многих. Хочется взять за проверочное "меридиан", но не тут-то было. Запомнить-то нетрудно, что меридиональный пишется через О - и слово это словарное.

Но вот натолкнулся на синонимичное меридианный - оно-то через А без вопросов.
И призадумался, а как получилось, что меридиональный спокон веку пишут через О? Должно ж быть какое-то логическое объяснение, это не тот случай, когда можно объяснить божьим попущением или "так звезды встали". Видимо, корни - в латыни, может быть французском, но я теряюсь в догадках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Меридиональный" первоначально не имело смыслового родства с "меридианом" и означало "полуденный" или "южный", от новолатинского meridionalis (Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. Чудинов А.Н., 1910), поэтому не было образовано в русском от этого слова. В более поздних словарях (напр. Ушакова) эти слова связали по смыслу со ссылкой на научную терминологию.

Comment: Ну да, спасибо, это я уже понял. Но Вы тоже прошли мимо лингвистической сути вопроса. Меридиан и меридиональный - однокоренные? Или корневой супплетивизм? Без этого и рассуждать о причинах смысла нет большого.

Comment: Ответ я принял, основной вопрос (см. пред. комментарий) остался без ответа.

Answer (score 1):

От существительного меридиан прилагательное можно образовать двумя способами:
меридиан - меридиан/н/ый, меридиан - мериди/ональн/ый.

Суффикс -ональн-  выделяется в словах: функция - функциональный, пропорция - пропорциональный.

Можно также сравнить: диагональ/н/ый - мериди/ональн/ый. Оба слова (меридиан и диагональ) пришли в русский язык в начале XVIII века, прилагательные "меридиональный и меридианный" известны с XIX века, здесь возможно взаимное влияние форм.

Comment: Да слов-то можно найти много. Если "-ональн(ый)" - единый суффикс, то что считать корнем? И верно ли что меридиан и меридиональный - однокоренные? Вот в чем лингвистическая суть вопроса.

Comment: А почему надо сомневаться, что слова однокоренные? В толковых словарях оба прилагательных отнесены к  существительному "меридиан".. У Черных то же самое, причем указано, что "меридиональный" впервые упоминается в 1804 году, а "меридианный" - в 1861 году. При образовании  прилагательного "мериди/ональн/ый" усечена основа, а при образовании "меридианный" добавлен суффикс "н", усечения основы нет.

Comment: Область применения прилагательных не совпадает: меридианный круг - суффикс "н" со значением общей отнесенности к предмету, меридиональный снежный хребет, меридиональный перенос воздушных масс - суффикс "ональн" со значением признака или свойства.

Comment: Во-1-х, откуда взяты эти значения? А во-2-х, при чем тут область приминения? Вы можете ответить, где корень в обоих словах или нет? Без потусторонних рассуждений? Разговоры про учечение основы - это вообще выше моего понимания. Хоть один подобный пример в русском есть? "Беларусь" не предлагать, там сами лингвисты запутались, где корень у этого уродца, появившегося в русском по воле филологов от политики. Хотя случай в чем-то похожий...

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, тут идет путаница с языками, как бывает, когда слово заимствовано из другого языка - так сказать, две парадигмы накладываются друг на друга и "интерферируют". Однако слово "меридиан" давно уже является "родным" русскому языку, и применение к нему правил именно русского языка не составляет проблем, кроме... Кроме одной-единственной - а именно созвучия, в случае с формой "меридиА..." с таким животрепещущим для многих словом и явлением, коих, к сожалению, немало. У тех, у кого слово в таком виде не вызывает болезненных ассоциаций, а соответствующая фантомная коннотация - повышенного внимания и интереса, и при этом не склонных к демонстрации напускной и сомнительной учености (*это же "meridionalis!", а не какой-то там меридиан + суффикс "аль"), не возникает трудностей с тем, чтобы писать образованное от "меридиан" прилагательное так, как это естественно для русского словообразования. Корень - "меридиан"  (и только "меридиан"), суффикс (для данной словообразовательной "модели") - "аль"+"н" (NB суффикс -аль- точно так же уже русифицировался и автономен от аналогичного латинского суффикса), получить прилагательное не сложно. Именно поэтому слово "меридианальный" устойчиво сосуществует с надуманным и навязываемым словарями "меридиональный", только затемняющим совершенно прозрачную этимологию прилагательного (относительного к "меридиан"). (В книгах, например, оно используется весь 20-й век.)  На мой взгляд, нет необходимости и зеркалить английское и т.д. meridiOnal (возникшее скорее всего во избежание той же ассоциации).

Что касается "меридианный", то это другое слово, и никто не запрещает его использовать наряду с прилагательным с суффиксом "-аль", но это совсем не относится к сути вопроса, который касается прилагательного с суффиксом "аль", имеющего более наукообразное звучание и использующего соответствующую словообразовательную модель (как в "зональный", "спинальный" и пр.).

Наконец, на частный вопрос, является ли слово с О однокоренным к "меридиан", - ответ "да", НО посредством латыни. Супплетивизм тут, таким образом, лишь условный.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51140/discussion-on-answer-by-user184835---).